# Flutter: How to obtain text entered from Autocomplete field instead of selecting a suggestion?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

Flutter provides an [Autocomplete widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html). If I enter `"abc"` instead of selecting one of the suggestions, then how can I get this text `"abc"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another variable to hold the input String inside state class like  `String? _inputString;` and update value inside `optionsBuilder`

```dart
class _AutocompleteBasicExampleState extends State<AutocompleteBasicExample> {
  String? _inputString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        setState(() {
          _inputString = textEditingValue.text;
        });
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thx